# Updating a dictionary item with a Tuple Key

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dictionary

I have a dictionary, which I am populating from an object, which in turn gets its data from two different sources:

1. a simple for loop which populates the keys, and
2. an `IEnumerable` which is basically a query.

I have managed to do the first bit of course, but am finding it a bit tricky to do the other. I do not know how can I exactly retrieve an object from the dictionary using a single component of 'double tuple'. This is what I have done though:

```
public class DictionaryValues
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public DateTime WeekStartingDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
    public decimal DueQuantity { get; set; }
    public int MaterialID { get; set; }
}

public static Dictionary<Tuple<int, int, DateTime>, DictionaryValues>
    GetIncomingStockDatesWithinForecastPeriod(IEnumerable<PurchaseOrder> purchaseOrders)
{
    var incomingStockDates = new Dictionary<Tuple<int, DateTime>, DictionaryValues>();

    var listDictionaryValues = new List<DictionaryValues>();

    for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
    {
        var dictValuesObj = new DictionaryValues();

        var timeNow = Utilities.RemoveTimeFromDate(DateTime.Now);

        dictValuesObj.Index = i;
        dictValuesObj.WeekStartingDate = timeNow;

        timeNow.AddDays(1);

        listDictionaryValues.Add(dictValuesObj);
    }


    // Populate the keys
    foreach (var dictValuesObj in listDictionaryValues)
    {
        incomingStockDates.Add(Tuple.Create(dictValuesObj.Index, dictValuesObj.WeekStartingDate), dictValuesObj);
    }

    // Populate other values

    foreach (var purchaseOrder in purchaseOrders)
    {
        if (purchaseOrder.DueDate == incomingStockDates.Keys.First().Item2)
        {
            var dictValuesObj = new DictionaryValues();
            dictValuesObj.DueDate = purchaseOrder.DueDate;
            dictValuesObj.DueQuantity = purchaseOrder.Quantity;
            dictValuesObj.MaterialID = purchaseOrder.MaterialID;

            // Update dictionary here and if the DueDate and MaterialID
            // are already there then add this Quantity to the existin one
        }
    }
}
```

So what I would like to do is simply retrieve an object by the dictionary-key's second component, update that and then if an object already exists with the same `DueDate` and `MaterialDate` to simply add the new quantity to the existing one on that `DueDate` for the `MaterialID`.

Comment: I think your approach is all wrong and bound to cause problems. If you intend to update a key then a dictionary just isn't the data source for you. What happens when some other code that is holding the old key in memory attempts to access that value? Oh it gets a `KeyNotFoundException`. I would recommend rethinking your problem altogether. Also, your key should be just that, a key. Not a Tuple with values in it that carry meaning.

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal I didn't intend to update the key but only use it to update the value.

Comment: @OndrejJanacek thanks I took note.

Answer (score 1):

To go along with the other answer, I think this is a good opportunity to utilize OO more. Also, rename DictionaryValues to something meaningful. I chose StockData, but it can be whatever fits.

```
public class StockDatas {
    public StockDatas(IEnumerable<PurchaseOrder> purchaseOrders) {

    }

    public StockData GetByDay(int day) {
        // Create an object from the purchaseOrders brought in from the constructor
    }

    public Dictionary<int, StockData> GetStockDataGroupedByDay() {
        // Create a dictionary keyed by the day number
    }
}
```

Then your code would be pretty clean.

```
var stockDates = new StockDates(data);
var stocksOnDayThree = stockDates.GetByDay(3);
var stocksOnAllDays = stockDates.GetStockDataGroupedByDay();
```

Then you will not have to deal with having a Tuple as the key